# What makes Python a good scripting language?

Tags: python, scripting

If you have to choose a scripting language, why would you choose Python?

Comment: voted for closing as subjective, unless converted to community wiki

Comment: this is a very subjective question.

Comment: Come on!If you want to save your question, do it a Wiki.You won't get any mercy....

Comment: so what it is subjective? it is a valid question, and searching the internet does give me some theories but no concrete answers. So, I thought I'll take your opinion. Is that a problem?

Comment: You have to make a question a wiki, if it doesn't have a specific and fixed answer.This is the definition of Wiki at SO.

Comment: okay ppl, I thought wiki was for polls etc. This is a wiki now!!

Comment: Yes even polls can lead to wiki...

Comment: Curiously, on reading the first answers any sane person will learn to steer clear of Python and its fans.

Comment: @hanifr, its as subjective as saying, why would you choose Pepsi over Coca Cola as your favourite drink. Therefore, if you think deeper, there will be NO real solution to your question, ever.

Comment: because pepsi does not taste like coke.

Comment: Point of clarification:  Although Python can be used to script other programs, I don't consider it a scripting language.  It's really more of a general-purpose programming language that happens to be so bloody easy to work with that many of us also end up using it when scripting is needed.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because it has clean and agile syntax, it's fast, well documented, well connected to C, has a lot of libraries, it's intuitive, and it's not perl.

Comment: @Stefano Borini
 whats wrong with perl?

Comment: I don't like it.

Comment: True,False=False,True # (excluding py3k :-)

Comment: Fast is not an adjective I have heard applied to python code before.

Comment: list and dictionary methods are very fast since they are implemented as optimized native (C) code under the python interface wrappers.  Sorting in python (via timsort) is particularly fast.  Since substantial portions of the python standard library are written in C, it is difficult to know beforehand how fast any given code snippet is going to be until you time.timeit().  Or you're a bot.  But it can be slow or fast, depending on what you're doing and how that is implemented.

Comment: Python is incredibly fast* *WOOSH* `{}` -- and there you have an optimized, string-tuned hash table you can't tune better yourself.

Answer (score 11):

Depends on what you mean by "scripting language".  If you mean I'm going to be extensively typing it in at a shell prompt, I want the mysterious but utter conciseness of Bash or zsh; if you mean I'm going to have to embed it in 2000 apps in each of which it will typically be used for "customization" scripts of 2 or 3 lines, I probably want the minimalist simplicity of Lua (I may not like *programming* in Lua all that much, but 2-3 lines is indeed "scripting" more than "programming", and the near-zero cost of embedding Lua in anything will then dominate).

Python, like Perl or Ruby, is mostly used to write MUCH more substantial "scripts" (impossible to distinguish from "programs", except maybe by total bigots;-) -- in which case, very different considerations apply wrt "real" **scripting** languages such as bash or zsh, or lua or tcl for a different definition of "scripting language".  Basically, if what you want is a dynamically (but strongly) typed language, with full capacity to scale up to very large software systems, and yet quite good at "playing with others"... then you surely have a **particularly** weird definition of "scripting", my friend!-)  But that's the arena where Python, Ruby and Perl mostly play -- and where one could debate one against the other (but any one of them would crush any other popular language I know -- yeah, I've known and loved and used rexx, scheme, Smalltalk, and many many others, but none could hold a candle to the Big Three I just mentioned in **this** arena!-).

But unless you clarify your terminology, "scripting language" remains an empty, meaning-free sound, and any debate surrounding it utterly useless and void of significance.

Comment: +for really getting at the terminology

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on your definition of scripting language. There are (at least) two camps. One is that scripting language should be embeddable, so the core should be small (like Lua or Tcl). The second camp is scripting for system administration, and Perl is definitely in this camp.

Python is a general programming language, not particularly in either camp (but also not unsuitable), probably most useful for writing small or medium sized programs.

Answer (score 0):

because it helps you in RAD, its the best language for writing opensource software

Take a look at this link http://www.python.org/about/

Answer (score 0):

*I would try a number of "scripting" languages (as well as some languages with good static type inference), and then select the language(s) that best fit the problem.*

This may be for a number of reasons including, but not limited to: Runtime targets and performance (as dictated by functional requirements), library support (don't re-invent the wheel *all* the time), existing tool support, existing integration support (if X supports Y, is it real feasible to get X to support Z just to use Z?), and **most important to a subjective question: personal choice and zealot fanaticism :)**

*The term "scripting language" is absolutely horrid* -- unless perhaps you really *DO* mean SH or MIRC "script". The phrase "dynamically typed language" is a much better qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed in python before but my guess would be the libraries available and the size of the userbase.

Comment: +1 for size of libraries.  PyPI (formerly the Cheese Shoppe) is large, and on its way to becoming huge.

Answer (score 0):

It's very intuitive, has a ton of libraries, helps you whip up a script VERY FAST. You can use it for small projects or big projects and can compile into an EXE for windows, an APP for mac or into a cross platform application.

I has possibly the cleanest syntax of any language I have seen to date and can do everything from adding numbers to system calls to reading various different types of files. Hell, you can even do web programming with it.

I see no reason why I would advise against python... ever.

Answer (score 0):

read http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

it this short article you can see many power features and elegance.
Especially things like defaultdict makes your code much more shorter, readable and maintainable.